# Attempt to build Centos8 rootfs and docker image appears to hang on required user interaction with no means of access

Tags: docker, centos

Has anyone made or found a centos8 docker image or the official rootfs tarball?   I can find all of these for centos7 but nothing for centos8

I'm working through what I believe is the [official how to](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-build/tree/master/docker) and am running into problems with livemedia-creator configuration.

The process appears to be that one uses livemedia-creator to transform the centos8 boot.iso into a rootfs tarball.  After this, the Dockerfile basically contains the rootsfs tarball and a few labels.

The problem is what when I run the process it seems to stall waiting on user input within the virtual environment and attempts to access the console or bolt a vnc instance to it fail.

## Command

```
livemedia-creator --make-tar --iso=/root/boot8.iso \
--ks=/root/centos-8.ks --image-name=centos8-docker.tar.xz
```

## Stall point

```
Domain installation still in progress. You can reconnect to 
the console to complete the installation process.
```

Attempts to connect via `virsh console` connect to a console with no interaction.  Attempts to use `--vnc ...` fail because graphics are disabled by livemedia-creator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centos recently released the centos8 image.  It is delayed from the rest of the release by a week+ probably because they generate images once per month.  Seems weird to me but it's their free OS which I'd like to use, so gratitude.

https://hub.docker.com/_/centos